# Linked Queue in Java not enqueuing properly

Tags: java, linked-list

I have this `LinkedQueue.java` class which implements from `QueueInterface.java`

When I try to enqueue data, it does something weird, the **1st** value to enqueue is *somewhat ignored*, and then when running the **2nd** enqueue it enqueues the **1st** value. When running the **3rd** enqueue it enqueues the **2nd** value. Finally, running the **4th** enqueue enqueues the **3rd** value, and the final **4th** value is *never enqueued*.

[Here is a screenshot of my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJmlO.png)

Here is the code which tests the code (enqueues and dequeues):

```
public class QueueTest3
{   public static void main(String[] args)
    {   QueueInterface<Integer> queue = new LinkedQueue<Integer>();
        
        //use enqueue method
        System.out.println("\nenqueuing -1");
        queue.enqueue(-1);
        queue.display();
        System.out.println("\nenqueuing 0");
        queue.enqueue(0);
        queue.display();
        System.out.println("\nenqueuing 1");
        queue.enqueue(1);
        queue.display();
        System.out.println("\nenqueuing 5");
        queue.enqueue(5);
        queue.display();
        
        while (!(queue.isEmpty()))
        {  //remove head element
           int removedItem = queue.dequeue();
           System.out.printf("%n%d dequeued%n", removedItem);
           queue.display();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my enqueue method.

```
 public void enqueue(T newEntry)
   { 
    Node newNode = new Node(newEntry, null);

    if (lastNode == null){
      firstNode = lastNode = newNode;
      return;
    }
    lastNode.setNextNode(newNode);
    lastNode = newNode;
    numNodes++;
    }
```

I'm stumped, I have rewritten the enqueue code many times. It went from actually giving out errors, to this.
How can I solve this?

Comment: What does `enqueue` do for second and subsequent nodes that it doesn't do for the first node? If you step through `enqueue` with the debugger you will see the problem immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to increment the numNodes in enqueue if it is the first node:

```java
public void enqueue(T newEntry) {
        Node newNode = new Node(newEntry, null);

        if (lastNode == null) {
            firstNode = lastNode = newNode;
            numNodes++;
            return;
        }
        lastNode.setNextNode(newNode);
        lastNode = newNode;
        numNodes++;
    }
```

or slightly cleaner imo

```java
public void enqueue(T newEntry) {
        Node newNode = new Node(newEntry, null);
        numNodes++;
        if (lastNode == null) {
            firstNode = lastNode = newNode;
            return;
        }
        lastNode.setNextNode(newNode);
        lastNode = newNode;
    }
```